# Re-occuring security notices for Access runtime application after re-installing Office 2010

Tags: ms-access-2007, office-2010

A user of an application which runs on the Access 2007 runtime has had to uninstall and re-install Office 2010.

Now she gets the following security notice up to 8 times every time she runs the software.

These notices only started to occur after re-installing Office 2010.

How can she stop the security notices? Why does this happen?

Thanks

[image: Security notice]

Comment: I think that re-installing Office 2010 cleared the trusted locations in the registry so the application will need to be re-installed to reset it. I used to think that C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\ (where the software is installed) is a trusted location by default and does not need to be set but I could be wrong.

Comment: I found this website yesterday and it has a nice script for adding a trusted file. http://www.amandhally.net/2012/08/31/setting-microsoft-office-2010-trust-centers-trusted-location-paths-using-powershell/

Comment: @TKEyi60 it may be worth offering that script as an answer. Although I might not be able to use it myself to solve the issue, others might, and I would certainly vote it up as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This happens whenever you try to run a macro or VBA with a strict or moderate security policy.  The only way (that I know of) to fix it is to go into the Options from File, then click Trust Center, and Trust Center Settings.

BE WARNED this can be dangerous because if she/he were to download a file with a virus it will automatically run it without prompting the user.

Comment: The users of the software do not have access to the menus because of the way the software is built. In any case, would there not be a way to revert the situation to how it was before the re-installation of Office 2010? The notices were not triggered before then (as stated in question).

Comment: A) The trust center is can be accessed from any MS 2010 program such as Excel or Word.  This will then modify the trust setting in all applications.  B) Are you sure the user cannot hold the SHIFT key while opening the project to get to the menu bar?

Comment: yes I am sure because it is disabled in code. :) I am aware of registry editing too, but would prefer to avoid it as I would be most likely guiding the user, or connecting to their PC, remotely to do this. It's an option but I was hoping for a simpler one.

Comment: Re-installing the application may be the simple answer but I am just waiting for the user to do this and then I will confirm it as the answer if it works.